# google spreadsheet set row background color based on note

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google spreadsheet that has client contact information in it.

I am trying to find a way to highlight edits users make automatically without them having to change the row color to say that they edited it.

What I was thinking of doing is when a user edits a cell is to add a note to that cell with the users email address. Then have it check to see if the note that was added to that cell equals a certain email address to set the background color of the row to whatever I specify.

The below adds a note of the users email address to the edited cell and sets the background color of the edited cell to red but not the entire row.

Any ideas on how to do this and if there is a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do.

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var cell = ss.getActiveCell();
  var range = ss.getActiveRange();
  var note = cell.getNote();
  var user = Session.getUser();

  note = user;
  cell.setNote(note);



  if(note = "user@email.com") {
    range.setBackgroundRGB(255, 0, 0);
  }

};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the entire row, assume it starts at 1, and use the `Range.getLastColumn()` method to find the right-extent of the row. (If your rows are staggered, this may highlight empty cells at either end - checking for that, though, will slow down the function further.)

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var cell = ss.getActiveCell();
  var range = sheet.getRange(cell.getRow(),1,1,sheet.getDataRange().getLastColumn());
  var note = cell.getNote();
  var user = Session.getUser();

  note = user;
  cell.setNote(note);

  if(note = "user@email.com") {
    range.setBackgroundRGB(255, 0, 0);
  }
};
```

You also asked about a "better way". Here's a variation with a few 'improvements'.

- It uses the trigger Event, rather than relying on being a container-bound script. (See [Understanding Events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events).) That makes this more portable, sure, but it also means that you can eliminate some (slow) calls to Spreadsheet services, since you're handed information for free.

  To test this function, use the technique described in [How can I test a trigger function in GAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089041/how-can-i-test-a-trigger-function-in-gas).
- Your original script contained an `if-then` to check which user had made a change, the beginning of a code block that would grow as you added more users. This one takes a data-driven approach, with `const userColors`. Then, we can check whether the user is known by an `in` comparison, and act on that.

  You could further improve it by managing the user colors in the spreadsheet, or elsewhere - and even having it dynamically learn new users and assign them their own colors. At any rate, this allows you to easily add more user & color combinations, without needing to change the logic in the function.
- In `onEdit()` functions, you should be very concerned about performance. (This example is so short, it's not really an issue, but still a good habit.) This version has a couple of changes to address that. First, there is a check to see if we need to set color at all - if the cell being edited was last edited by the same user, there's no need to do anything else. Second, a number of operations that invoke Spreadsheet Services have been moved so they only execute when needed.

Updated script:

```
function onEdit(event) {
  const userColors = {
    'user1@email.com' : 'red',
    'user2@email.com' : 'blue',
    'user3@email.com' : '#ff00ff'
  };

  var note = event.range.getNote();
  var user = new String(Session.getUser());

  // update note and color if new editor
  if (note != user) {
    var sheet = event.range.getSheet();
    var range = sheet.getRange(event.range.getRow(),1,1,sheet.getLastColumn());

    event.range.setNote(user);
    
    if (user in userColors) range.setBackground(userColors[user]);
    // don't color unknown users
    else range.setBackground('white');
  }
};
```

Comment: Nice example of events. Not something I've used much. Why aren't you using `getMaxColumn`?

Comment: @fooby - Because `getMaxColumn()` gives you the width of the entire spreadsheet, while `getLastColumn()` gives the extent of the range. My preference is to restrict formatting to the portion of the spreadsheet that contains data.

Comment: Fair enough. I guess the best way to visually display recently updated information is a discussion all it's own. I'll have to give some thought to that...

Answer (score 1):

I've also taken a look. The `getLastColumn` will give you the last column which contains data on the entire sheet, ignoring empty rows beyond that, [see here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getLastColumn%28%29). If you want the entire row, you should use `getMaxColumns()`, [see here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getMaxColumns%28%29)

Checking for the value of the note after running `setNote` is redundant. eg

```
var i = 1;
if(i === 1) { dosomething(i) }
```

There are a few things that came to mind when thinking about this feature is a spreadsheet.

- Different users having different colors.

  - I would have a color selection option and store that in `ScriptDB`
- Clearing the colors on "approval" or some other condition

  - I would use a menu option that is visible only to the correct users
- Keeping track of users notes

  - I would have a key which is appended to the end of any existing note (and overwritten if the key already exists). Then, I would use regex `note.search(/editor:.*?$/i)` to check for the key later and overwrite it.

---

Here's my quick version of the `onEdit` function.

```
function onEdit() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();

  var rowNum = cell.getRow();
  var row = sheet.getRange(rowNum, 1, 1, sheet.getMaxColumns());

  var user = Session.getActiveUser();

  cell.setNote("Edited by: " + user.getEmail());
  row.setBackground("red");
}
```

Comment: That check isn't redundant - the OP indicated they wanted different colors for different users.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that he wanted to use different colors for different users, but his example doesn't wouldn't do that. A switch or other method would need to be uses. I was simply pointing out that to just change the color, the check wasn't required.