# How to change whole row color in google script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How can I change whole rows background color of active cell in google script?

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().setBackgroundRGB(224, 102, 102)
```

The code above only changes active cells background color.
But I need to change row of active cells background.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) and [Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) have methods you can use to pick the row that the cell is in. This is similar to the technique used in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17342762/google-spreadsheet-set-row-background-color-based-on-note/17343844#17343844).

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getRow(),1,1,SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastColumn()).setBackgroundRGB(224, 102, 102);
```

This does the same thing, broken down into easier-to-read lines:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
var changeRange = sheet.getRange(activeRange.getRow(),1,1,sheet.getLastColumn());
changeRange.setBackgroundRGB(224, 102, 102);
```