# Using setConditionalFormatRules() in google sheets to highlighte a row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a conditional fomatting applyed using "whenTextEqualTo" case. This works fine and the cell, which meets this conditions highlighted as desired.
However, I would like to have the row to be highlighted , in which this cell is found.

So, the sheet *FinData* has data located in range from **A2** to **G500**. The value I am checking is in the column **F** (value should be == "CDI"). When this is met, the cell is highlighted .
How to do the same but with the row being highlighted , i.e. col B to col G inclusively.
I have checked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367503/how-to-change-whole-row-color-in-google-script) but could not incorporate it into mine below:

```
function formatCDI() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var finDataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("FinData");
  var range = finDataSheet.getRange("A2:G500");
  finDataSheet.clearConditionalFormatRules();

  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()

    .whenTextEqualTo("CDI")
    .setBackground("#86D3FF")
    .setRanges([range])
    .build();
  var rules = finDataSheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  rules.push(rule);
  finDataSheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
};
```

Would apprecaite any help on this.
Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to apply the highlight for the column from "B" to "G" using the conditional formatting, when the value of column "F" is `CDI`.

If my understanding is correct, how about using `whenFormulaSatisfied()` instead of `whenTextEqualTo()`. In your case, as the formula, `=$F2="CDI"` is used.

### Modified script:

Please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
var range = finDataSheet.getRange("A2:G500");
```

And

```
.whenTextEqualTo("CDI")
```

#### To:

```
var range = finDataSheet.getRange("B2:G500");
```

And

```
.whenFormulaSatisfied('=$F2="CDI"')
```

### Reference:

- [whenFormulaSatisfied(formula)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule-builder#whenformulasatisfiedformula)

If I misunderstood your question, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: All is correct - thank you! Of course ".whenFormulaSatisfied" is the one to go! Apprecaite it! –

Comment: @AlexShevyakov Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.